# Jasmine: Expected object not to have properties

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine

I write tests for models using Jasmine and receive the following error stack:

```
$ yarn test 
yarn run v1.22.10
$ ENV=test db-migrate --env test up && jasmine-ts && db-migrate db:drop test
received data: /* Replace with your SQL commands */
CREATE TABLE books (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY  KEY,
    title VARCHAR(150),
    total_pages INTEGER,
    author VARCHAR(255),
    summary text
);



[INFO] Processed migration 20210804043247-books-table
[INFO] Done
test
Randomized with seed 85003
Started
......F.

Failures:
1) Book Model create method should add a book
  Message:
    Expected object to have properties
        totalPages: 250
    Expected object not to have properties
        total_pages: 250
  Stack:
    Error: Expected object to have properties
        totalPages: 250
    Expected object not to have properties
        total_pages: 250
        at <Jasmine>
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/chaklader/Documents/Education/Udacity/Udacity_Nano_Degree/Full_Stack_JavaScript_Developer/C_3/L_3/E_4/src/models/tests/book_spec.ts:36:24)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

8 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 0.04 seconds
Randomized with seed 85003 (jasmine --random=true --seed=85003)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The `book.ts` provided below:

```
import client from "../database";

export type Book = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    totalPages: number;
    summary: string;
}

export class BookStore{

    async index(): Promise<Book[]> {
        try {
          // @ts-ignore
          const conn = await client.connect();
          const sql = 'SELECT * FROM books';
    
          const result = await conn.query(sql);
    
          conn.release();
    
          return result.rows; 
        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(`Could not get books. Error: ${err}`);
        }
      }
    
      async show(id: string): Promise<Book> {
        try {
        const sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=($1)'
        // @ts-ignore
        const conn = await client.connect()
    
        const result = await conn.query(sql, [id])
    
        conn.release()
    
        return result.rows[0]
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(`Could not find book ${id}. Error: ${err}`)
        }
      }
    
      async create(b: Book): Promise<Book> {
          try {
        const sql = 'INSERT INTO books (title, author, total_pages, summary) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *'
        // @ts-ignore
        const conn = await client.connect()
    
        const result = await conn
            .query(sql, [b.title, b.author, b.totalPages, b.summary])
    
        const book = result.rows[0]
    
        conn.release()
    
        return book
          } catch (err) {
              throw new Error(`Could not add new book ${b.title}. Error: ${err}`)
          }
      }
    
}
```

The test file `book_spec.ts` is below:

```
import { Book, BookStore } from '../book';

const store = new BookStore();

describe('Book Model', () => {
    it('should have an index method', () => {
        expect(store.index).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a show method', () => {
        expect(store.show).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a create method', () => {
        expect(store.create).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a update method', () => {
        expect(store.create).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a delete method', () => {
        expect(store.delete).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('create method should add a book', async () => {

        const result = await store.create({
            id: 1,
            title: 'Bridge to Terabithia',
            author: 'Katherine Paterson',
            totalPages: 250,
            summary: 'Childrens',
        });

        expect(result).toEqual({
            id: 1,
            title: 'Bridge to Terabithia',
            totalPages: 250,
            author: 'Katherine Paterson',
            summary: 'Childrens',
        });
    });

});
```

The data is populated properly in the bd:

[image]

The SQL statement in the bd migration is provided:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY  KEY,
    title VARCHAR(150),
    total_pages INTEGER,
    author VARCHAR(255),
    summary text
);
```

What's the issue here and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Book` has camelCase properties but your `books` table has snake_case properties. You either need to pick one type of casing for both or when you get the result from the database create a new object that is of type `Book`.

```
const book = {
  id: result.rows[0].id,
  title: result.rows[0].title,
  author: result.rows[0].author,
  totalPages: result.rows[0].total_pages,
  summary: result.rows[0].summary
}
```

Another option is to use something like [lodash.camelcase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.camelcase) and map the object keys to convert them.